# Summing specific numbers in list as specified by another list

Tags: python

Okay so I have two lists. One of strings 'addition' or 'subtraction', and one of integers. like so

```
valueTypes = ['addition', 'subtraction', 'subtraction','addition', 'subtraction']

valueAmounts = [100, 52, 47, 734, 99]
```

each index of the valueTypes list is associated with its respective index from the valueAmounts list. That is to say 100 is 'addition', 52 is 'subtraction'...ect.

How can I sum just the valueAmount numbers that are associated with just 'addition' strings or just 'subtraction' strings, from valueTypes?

Answer (score -2):

Use `zip` to connect the pairs, and use `sum` to add the relevant numbers together:

```
>>> valueTypes = ['addition', 'subtraction', 'subtraction','addition', 'subtraction']
>>> valueAmounts = [100, 52, 47, 734, 99]
>>> sum(b for a,b in zip(valueTypes, valueAmounts) if a=='addition')
834
```